# running pytest, pylint against aws lambda images, not the handler function

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, pytest

I have a `aws lambda` function, deployed using a docker image. I want to run some unit-tests against my code, but not the `handler` function.
is there a way that I can do that?

I have seen the docs, stating that I should run the function, and use `requests` or other means of sending requests and analyzing the results, but is there a way to just run `pytest` against that code?
I have `docker-compose` and I run my tests like following:

```
run_test:
    export PYTHONPATH="./${ROOT_MODULE_FOLDER}" && pytest ${ROOT_MODULE_FOLDER}/*.py

test:
    docker-compose run --rm app make run_test
```

These commands are living in a `Makefile` where I run `make test` and expect `pytest` to run. but I get:

```
entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
```

which is complaining about running the docker image. OK! I add an `command` in the compose file:

```
...
...
ports:
- "9000:8080"
command: ["hello_world_app.handler.handler"]  #module_name.file_name.handler_function_name
```

I can run the `curl` command against it:

```
 curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

and I receive

```
"hello world!"
```

which is correct. but when I try to run `make test` I get

```
entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument
```

I can run just `pytest` or `pylint` locally on my machine on the code, and all is good, but I can't do it in the container, which I need to run, for my `CI`.

Comment: Would it be an option to run the unit test before packaging them into docker image? or follow naming convention for python tests test_xxx.py/xxx_test.py and run `pytest` to detect test automatically

Comment: currently I am doing that, running all those commands before packaging to docker. just wanted to see if it's possible to do it inside the docker too or not. files are named `test_X.py`, but I do that `*.py` thing because I don't know why! I just do it because our other codes have that:/

Comment: I believe u can. You need to override ENTRYPOINT and CMD to do so. I just see very little sense to package test files into lambda docker image. You pay for space. So every byte cost something :)